# Windows Platform supported by Cordova

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Cordova Plugins :

```
org.apache.cordova.device
org.apache.cordova.dialogs
org.apache.cordova.geolocation
org.apache.cordova.network-information
enter code hereorg.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

mention Windows phone 7 and 8 as supported platforms. Do these plugins also support Windows phone 8.1 and will support windows phone 10 ??

Comment: According to cordova's platform guide Windows 8.1 and WP8.1 are supported. But nothing yet about Windows 10. http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_win8_index.md.html

Comment: Link says that we can develop apps for Windows 8 +, but the plugin documentation says that, supported platforms are 7 and 8,,, no name of 8.1.. I want to confirm if plugins will work or not for windows phone 8+..

Answer (score -1):

The documentation says:

> firefoxos,  android,  browser,  amazon-fireos,  ubuntu,  ios,  blackberry10,  wp7,  wp8,  windows8,  **windows**

..with Windows meaning the Windows Store app API. Since version 8.1 Windows Store app code also runs on Windows Phone. So I'm fairly sure this will work.

Also, if you scroll down you can read about Windows Phone 8.1 in the "quirks" part on some pages. So since they are even mentioning it, WP 8.1 should be supported.